# pthread mutex lock - Does it check periodically or OS wakes it up

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, posix

If Thread1 tried to lock resource locked by Thread2. 
Does it go to sleep for finite time ?

Now if the Thread2 unlock the mutex then how would Thread1 will come to know that resource is available ? Is the operating system wakes it up or it checks for resource periodically ?

Comment: OS wakes it up.

Comment: process to wake it up ?

Answer (score 3):

your second assumption is correct. When a mutex is locked by a thread already, all the remaining threads that are trying to lock it again will be placed on hold and will be in the sleep state. Once the mutex lock is unlocked the O/S wakes them all up and who can unlock first can access the lock. This is not in FIFO basis, actually there is no rule which thread should get first preference to lock the mutex once wakes up. You can consider my below example where I have use condition variable to control the threads:-

```
pthread_cond_t cond1 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond2 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond3 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t lock1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t lock2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t lock3 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int TRUE = 1;

void print(char *p)
{
  printf("%s",p);
}

void * threadMethod1(void *arg)
{
  printf("In thread1\n");
  do{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond1, &lock1);
    print("I am thread 1st\n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond3);/* Now allow 3rd thread to process */
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
  }while(TRUE);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void * threadMethod2(void *arg)
{
  printf("In thread2\n");
  do
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock2);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond2, &lock2);
    print("I am thread 2nd\n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock2);
  }while(TRUE);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void * threadMethod3(void *arg)
{
  printf("In thread3\n");
  do
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock3);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond3, &lock3);
    print("I am thread 3rd\n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond2);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock3);
  }while(TRUE);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t tid1, tid2, tid3;
  int i = 0;

  printf("Before creating the threads\n");
  if( pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, threadMethod1, NULL) != 0 )
        printf("Failed to create thread1\n");
  if( pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, threadMethod2, NULL) != 0 )
        printf("Failed to create thread2\n");
  if( pthread_create(&tid3, NULL, threadMethod3, NULL) != 0 )
        printf("Failed to create thread3\n");
  pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);/* Now allow first thread to process first */


  sleep(1);
  TRUE = 0;/* Stop all the thread */
  sleep(3);

 /* this is how we join thread before exit from a system */
  /*  
  pthread_join(tid1,NULL);
  pthread_join(tid2,NULL);
  pthread_join(tid3,NULL);*/

 exit(0);
}
```

Here I am using 3 mutexs and 3 conditions. With the above example you can schedule/control or prioritize any number of threads in C. If you see the first thread here it locked mutex lock1 and waiting on cond1, likewise second thread locked mutex lock2 and waits on condition cond2 and 3rd thread locked mutex lock3 and waits on condition cond3. This is the current situation of all the threads after they are being created and now all the threads are waiting for a signal to execute further on its condition variable. In the main thread (i.e. main function, every program has one main thread, in C/C++ this main thread created automatically by operating system once control pass to the main method by kernal) we are calling pthread_cond_signal(&cond1); once this system call done thread1 who was waiting on cond1 will be release and it will start executing. Once it finished with its task it will call pthread_cond_signal(&cond3); now thread who was waiting on condition cond3 i.e. thread3 will be release and it will start execute and will call pthread_cond_signal(&cond2); which will release the thread who is waiting on condition cond2 i.e. in this case thread2.

Comment: Re, "...This is not in FIFO basis."  Documentation for [`pthread_mutex_lock(mutex)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_mutex_lock.html) does not say anything about the order in which threads will acquire a contested mutex.  It could work the way you say in one implementation, and it could work differently in some other implementation.

Comment: I have mentioned that based on my own experience. People might think that the thread which tried to lock  a mutex first will get the first opportunity to lock it and start executing the code. This is not in FIFO basis means no prioritization in wake up threads. So there is no any order. I have corrected by answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Fundamental information about the mutex (MUtual Exclusion locks)**

A mutex is a special lock that only one thread may lock at a time. If a thread locks a mutex and then a second thread also tries to lock the same mutex, the second thread is blocked, or put on hold. Only when the first thread unlocks the mutex is the second thread unblocked—allowed to resume execution.

- Linux guarantees that race conditions do not occur among threads attempting to lock a mutex; only one thread will ever get the lock, and all other threads will be blocked.
- A thread may attempt to lock a mutex by calling pthread_mutex_lock on it. If the mutex was unlocked, it becomes locked and the function returns immediately.

---

**What happens trying to lock the when its locked by another thread?**

If the mutex was locked by another thread, `pthread_mutex_lock` blocks execution and returns only eventually when the mutex is unlocked by the other thread.